# How to keep an image in the top right corner of my webpage when zooming in/out?

Tags: html, css, position

I have an image on my web page. The image is in its own div, and I have it in position:relative to move it to where I want on the page (roughly top right corner). My issue is, when I zoom out of my page, the image no longer appears in the right, it ends up appearing more to the left/top centre of my page (as you may expect). I have a paragraph of  my page expand when zooming out, but it is in its own div and below the image, just thought I'd mention that although it may be irrelevant. I want the image to stay in its place when zooming out, so it constantly budges up to the right to stay in position. Example with Google:

Sign in box in right at 100% zoom: https://snag.gy/9oMGVr.jpg

Sign in box still in right corner when zoomed out: https://snag.gy/FXArO4.jpg

Would like to do the same thing with my image, float:right6 seemed to not work.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you inspect the HTML/CSS of Google's website to find out how they do it in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see the fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v31nr71y/)

Important think is:

```
 position: fixed;
   right:0;
    top:0;
```

Always place in top_right corner

And apply with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`  in your html its will show the responsive design

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

```html
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <head>
    <style>
      .top_right{
  position: fixed;
width:70px;
height:30px;
margin:10px 5px auto;
background-color:blue;color:white;
right:0;
top:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:none;
}
 </style>
    </head>
  <body>
<button class="top_right">
SignIn
</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed positioning and it should then stay relative to the browser or view port.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<img class="pull-right img-responsive" src="images/img_c_2.jpg" />
</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <head>
    <style>
      .top_right{
  position: fixed;
width:70px;
height:30px;
margin:10px 5px auto;
background-color:blue;color:white;
right:0;
top:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:none;
}
 </style>
    </head>
  <body>
<button class="top_right">
SignIn
</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```